# Flying Saucer does not render background color and strikethrough

Tags: flying-saucer

Flying Saucer does not render the strikethrough for the following HTML sample:

```
<s><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">This is a test </span></span>
</s>
```

Only the background color and the colored text is shown on the generated PDF:
[image]

However, the strikethrough is properly rendered when not using a background color.

How can I get Flying Saucer to render the strikethrough when combined with a background color?

**Update June 6**

If I move the strike tag `<s>` inside of the span tags, then it works:

```
<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><s>This is a test</s></span></span>
```

Comment: Could this be related to the older version of CSS supported?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem in your CSS.

Here is an example which shows strikethrough working with flying-saucer (9.1.1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        span {
            color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
        }
        span.decorated {    text-decoration: line-through;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Without strikethrough</span>
    <span class="decorated">With strikethrough</span>
</body>
</html>
```

The result:

[image: Result with thrikethrough]

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the input is inline CSS only. Please see the sample code in my question

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `!important` for it to work in my case:

```
h2 { background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important; }
```

I was using it in the `<head><style>` section - didn't try inline.